# How can I control 4 DC motors with an Arduino?

Tags: arduino-mega, motor, arduino-motor-shield, robotics

In a few months, I am planning to construct an Arduino robot with multiple sensors etc. I will use an arduino mega and a 4wd chassis like the one here: [Chassis.](http://www.ebay.com/itm/NEW-4WD-Robot-Smart-Car-Chassis-Kits-car-with-Speed-Encoder-for-Arduino-M26/201561877173?_trksid=p2047675.c100009.m1982&_trkparms=aid%3D777000%26algo%3DABA.MBE%26ao%3D1%26asc%3D36860%26meid%3Dc76077722d4348e88152fa6c7f32c005%26pid%3D100009%26rk%3D1%26rkt%3D1%26sd%3D181329341315)  The chassis uses 4 DC motors. I was planning to use a motor shield, but I realized that it only fits an Arduino Uno(not Mega) and it controls only 2 DC motors. What can I do to make all 4 DC motors move forward and backward? If I use a motor driver board that controls 2 motors, can I connect the 2 right and 2 left motors in parallel together and the control it through the Arduino?

Comment: Use motor drivers that aren't on a shield.

Comment: @Majenko would I have to use 2 drivers then?

Comment: Each motor needs a driver. If a driver board can drive two motors then you need 2 driver boards for 4 motors. If a driver board can only drive 1 motor then you need 4 driver boards for 4 motors. Find a driver board that is powerful enough for your motors and then do the (*very simple*) maths.

Comment: If it can help, I have some code I'm using exactly for that purpose: https://github.com/igor-stoppa/ChibiOS/tree/car I haven't had much time lately to spend on it, but it does the basic. I'm using 2 of these: http://www.ebay.com/itm/111671736661?_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649&ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT

Comment: In theory, it's true that the 2 wheels on each side could be controlled by the same driver (assuming it can output enough power), however I'm not sure how this would play out when motors are either not sufficiently similar or subject to different load (say one has to overcome a small bump). So I preferred to play it safe and have each wheel controlled independently.

Comment: @IgorStoppa Each motor draws 120mA at 6 Volts. I have read about people controlling 2 motors together. I will probably control them individually so that I don't risk anything.

Comment: If you want to add a feedback loop to each motor, I found these optical end stop detectors to work quite well: http://www.ebay.com/itm/1-x-Optical-Endstop-End-Stop-Limit-Switch-Solution-for-3D-Printer-or-CNC-NEW-DE-/281983545137?hash=item41a7876f31:g:6UsAAOSwxcRW-UHJ

Comment: @IgorStoppa Do you recommend getting the Sparkfun driver or did the one you got from ebay work fine?

Comment: @NickSolonko when dealing with motors, you laso have to account for peak current consumption: overcoming the initial inertia will draw much more current than when steadily cruising. In general any change of speed (including steering) will cause a temporary increase.

Comment: So far, the driver I linked seems to be ok. I do not have experience with the one from Sparkfun. But I can advice to not buy any based on L298N because of the much higher internal power loss: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Dual-H-Bridge-DC-Stepper-Motor-Drive-Controller-Board-Module-Arduino-L298N-HG-/281551893660?hash=item418dccf49c:g:sm8AAOSwYGFUsJ9I

Comment: @IgorStoppa I was looking at buying something based on L298N. Thank you for warning me. Now I will probably get the one you advised. The one I was previously planning to get: http://www.ebay.com/itm/L298N-4-Channels-DC-Motor-Step-motor-Driver-Module-Robot-4WD-Car-for-Arduino-DG-/262482009259?hash=item3d1d259cab:g:srwAAOSw9eVXXnyk

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/41125/discussion-between-igor-stoppa-and-nick-solonko).

Comment: 6 volt motors expected to be well under an app would probably point to a TB6612FNG.  Some of the newer motor shields use those, as FET devices they are much lower loss.

Comment: @ChrisStratton: that's what I linked to.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do this using 2 L293D motor drivers, each motor driver can run 2 motors and it is very easy to use.
[image]

You should connect Vcc 1(used to power on the chip) to 5V and Vcc 2 to a power supply that is needed to run your motors, Enable 1,2 and Enable 3,4 are used to enable the 2 sides of the chip and should be connected to 5V. Outputs 1-4 are the outputs to 2 motors and Inputs 1-4 are the inputs from the micro-controller.

Comment: But, what if I want to use a separate power supply, such as a 9V battery?  How am I supposed to connect it to the L293D motor driver?  I think, I should connect the positive side of the 9V battery to the VCC 2 pin of the L293D motor driver.  But, where should I connect the negative side of the 9V battery?

Comment: You should connect the negative side to the 4 ground pins.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can actually do this, but you have to consider the current of the motors and the motor driver. For example, if you have 12V, 2 Amps motors, then you need a 2-channel motor driver that is able to output a little higher that 4 Amps (2*2 Amps) for each channel at 12V. You will need to connect each two motors on the same side in parallel to one channel.